# How to pass jwtPayload data decoded by Passport to nodejs API

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am using this passport strategy.

```
  passport.use(
    'onlyForRefreshToken',
    new JWTStrategy(
      {
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey: jwtSecretRider,

      },
      (jwtPayload, done) => {

        if (jwtPayload) {
          return done(null, jwtPayload); 
        }
        return done(null, false);
      },
    ),
  );
```

My goal is Putting 'jwtPayload' into my rest API of Nodejs that is located at other folder.
That is, I want to use jwtPayload decoded at the code below.

```
exports.riderRefreshToken = async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;

    const exRiderRefreshToken = await Rider.findOne({ email });
}
```

And this router works by middleware of jwtstrategy.

```
router.post(
  '/refreshToken',
  passport.authenticate('onlyForRefreshToken', { session: false }),
  authenticationCtrl.riderRefreshToken,
);
```

In conclusion, when JWT passes from jwtstrategy without problem, that Post router would work.
 And I want to use jwtPayload that is in jwtstrategy into Nodejs API as req.params or req.body.

Could you help me this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your strategy into a function that gets `req` and `res` :

```
const isAuthenticated: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate(
    'jwt',
    { session: false, failWithError: true },
    (error, user) => {
      if (error) {
        return next(error)
      }

      //HERE PUT USER WHERE YOU WANT
      //req.data or req.user or req.userInfo
      req.user = user

      return next()
    }
  )(req, res, next)
}
```

I don't recommend putting the user into `req.params` nor `req.body` since it might be confusing later on (because technically it doesn't come from those).